Не удается выровнять блок по x, scale и translate
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 200px;
transform: scale(1.7829131652661065) translate(-50%, -100%);
height: 57px;
width: 102px;



.gl {
   width: 500px;
   background:blue;
   aspect-ratio: 1;
   position: relative;
}
.ff {
  width: 200px;
  height: 5px;
  background:green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
}
.bl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  background:red;
  transform: scale(2) translate(-50%, 20px);
  height: 57px;
  width: 102px;
}
<div class='gl'>
   <div class='ff'></div>
   <div class='bl'></div>
</div>



У одного меня криво работает? Сперва необходимо масштабировать блок. Затем выровнять его по x. Без маштаба, ровно, кажется он не учитывает маштаб...

Без разметки и чёткого описания с примером воспроизводящим проблему, ничего конкретного сказать нельзя. Единственное, что можно сказать - порядок трансформаций ВАЖЕН!

Добавил пример, зеленый блок шириной 200px. После увеличения красного блока, окончание зеленого блока не по центру. То есть красный не по центру окончания зеленого

Необходимо помнить, что позиционирование происходит относительно верхнего левого угла элемента. Трансформации же производятся относительно центра (если это не изменено с помощью transform-origin) элемента и исходя из его размеров.
Повторюсь, порядок трансформаций в свойстве transform имеет значение.


.gl {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.ff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 5px; width: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.bl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 200px;
  height: 30px; width: 102px;
  transform: scale(2) translate(-50%, 20px);
  background: red;
}
.bl2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 200px;
  height: 30px; width: 102px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 20px) scale(2);
  background: #fc08;
}
<div class='gl'>
  <div class='ff'></div>
  <div class='bl'>bl</div>
  <div class='bl2'>bl2</div>
</div>



